# VIM check for search pattern match in vim script

Tags: vim

I just started with vim script and try make translation of opencart language files easier. I want to have a function that looks for a given search pattern and selects it. If there is no match left in the file, it shall open the next file for editing. What I have so far:

```
function! Nextmatch()
    normal /\(= *'\)\@<=.\{-\}\('\)\@=/
    normal v//e
endfunction

function! Nextfile()
   if !exists("s:filecounter")
        execute "!find -iname *.php > files.txt"
        normal <CR>
        let s:filecounter=0
   endif
   let s:lines= system("wc -l < files.txt")
   if s:filecounter<s:lines
        w
        let s:filecounter += 1
        let s:sedcommand="sed '".s:filecounter."!d' files.txt"
        let s:selectedfile=system(s:sedcommand)
        execute 'edit' s:selectedfile
   else
        wq
   endif
endfunction
```

How can I achieve that `Nextfile()` is called in `Nextmatch()` if the search pattern is not found between the cursor and the end of the current file? And is there something that you consider to be bad style in my snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quickfix commands are powerful and well integrated with some external plugins, but if you really need to use your own script, and if you need to check a match in an if statement, just do:

```
if search("=\\s*'\\zs[^']*\\ze", 'W') == 0
     echo 'No match until the end of the buffer'
endif
```

See `:h search()`, and please note :

- the double backslashes, due to the double quotes
- the `'W'` flag which forbids wrapping around the end of file
- I simplified the pattern you gave

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use the `:vim` command to get rid of all your script.

I think the following should do quite what you're expecting:

```
:noremap <f8> <esc>:cn<cr>gn
/\(= *'\)\@<=.\{-\}\('\)\@=
:vim //g *.php
```

Then, to go to the next pattern in all files while selecting it,
you just have to press the `F8` key.

In the `noremap` line, `gn` let you select the next actual search.

You may need to do:

```
:set nohidden
```

to let you navigate threw modified buffers (but don't forget to save
them with `:wa`, or list them with `:ls`)

About your script:

- It's a good habit in scripts to always use `:normal!` instead of `:normal` (unless you deliberately need it) : thus, your personnal mappings won't interfer in your scripts.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tested it and it is almost what I want. However there are two problems: 1. It is not relative to the cursor, i.e. if I do `:bnext` and then press `F8`, it jumps back to the old file and 2. It does not look in subdirectories. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Look into subdirs : `:vim //g **/*.php`

Comment: About the cursor position : it can't be done easily, since `:cn` just jumps to the next element in the quickfix list; See `:h quickfix`

Comment: I still can't believe that there seems to be no way to check for a search pattern match in an if statement. But this solution is sufficient for me and I learned a few things. Thanks!!